# Issues with giving permission to user PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, mariadb

I'm trying to give all permissions to a user on `phpmyadmin` so he can add a collation to his database. 
However, once I enter the command :

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';`

It displays :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: Please restart `MariaDB` Server. Try granting privileges with this script `GRANT ALL privileges ON *.* TO 'myuser'@localhost;`

Comment: No, don't need a restart, just `FLUSH PRIVILEGES:`  Anyway that can't be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

"... syntax error near 'GRANT ..." probably means that whatever was immediately before `GRANT` is the *real* syntax error.  Maybe a missing `;`?  Maybe something else.

"Syntax error" is very good at pointing exactly at, or immediately after, the offending token.